# Be "running late" and "run my appointment"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider this comment:

> My doctor is awesome. He was running late with a previous patient so he sent a new doctor to run my follow up appointment.

Does "running late" here means he is going to be late, or he is going to take more time than usual? What does it precisely mean? Also, what does *running* an appointment mean when he said they sent a new doctor to run his follow up appointment? Does it mean *to deal with*?

Comment: _To be running late_ means _to have overrun the allocated time_ (whether the allocation was strictly timetabled or just intended). _To run an appointment_ sounds odd to me - I'd use 'handle' or 'take care of'. 'Run' _does_ mean 'manage, conduct, perform...' (amongst many other things), but not all objects sit well with this verb.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hey I think this is a very good answer and deserves to be awarded. Can you please submit it as an answer?

Comment: Likewise.   And to explain the use of "run", it fits perfectly fine considering the doctor will be operating on Theo, and thus be "running the job". Maybe a little unusual, but nothing at all wrong with the way he used the term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Running late" is an idiomatic phrase that means, essentially, "late" or "being late," with the caveat that "being late" is more a translation than a phrase that people use. The Oxford English Dictionary defines it as:

- "s. to run late : to be behind schedule. Similarly to run early, on time, etc."

For your example, you could write "He was late so he sent a new doctor to run my follow up appointment." What's different about that way of saying it is that "running late" conveys information about why the doctor was late. He had a prior appointment and it took longer than expected. Perhaps it would be even better to write "He was taking longer than expected with a previous patient so he sent a new doctor to run my follow up appointment."

If you tell someone you are "running late" there are a few important connotations. First, it is probably in reference to a meeting or scheduled appointment. Second, you could already be late or simply anticipating that you will be late. That would depend on the time the message is conveyed relative to the appointment or scheduled time.

You are correct that "to run" the follow up appointment means approximately "to deal with." However, just know that at least in the United States, you don't normally "run" an appointment. It's understood, but not common. You might run a meeting but usually you "have" an appointment. I would have written it as "he sent a new doctor to meet with me for my follow up appointment.

I would also point you to [a discussion on WordReference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1270553) about this phrase.